# Assigning a integer variable to css from js code

Tags: javascript, css, sass

I want to change `history-length` variable in js code and use it in the following js code. How can I do this?

```
$history-length: 15;

@for $i from 0 through 3 {
  @for $j from 1 through $history-length {
    g:nth-child(#{$i*$history-length + $j}) > circle {
      fill: nth($colors, $i+1);
      stroke: nth($colors, $i+1);
    }
  }
}
```

First I tried like this in js code to manipulate the `--history-length` variable, but it seemed I only can not assign integer and use it in css code.

```
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty(`--history-length`, 15)
```

Next thing I did was export the variable from css code and import it in js code and change it. But it didn't change the variable in css code.

```
:export {
  historyLength: $history-length;
}
```

What else can I try?

Comment: You can use CSS variables and manipulate them with Javascript. It's hard to tell what you're trying to do here, please clarify.

Comment: I think you're using SASS over here. SASS gets compiled to CSS, so there's no concept of runtime variables. Have a look at CSS variables to do the same thing

Comment: Could you show us your SVG? It will be easier to explain what is going on. As @boxdox has outlined, the code you have shown is not JS it is SASS which is a pre-processor, it cannot change things once it's compiled to CSS and the app is running. But your setting of the CSS variable can be made to work.

Comment: @AHaworth yeah, they can use css variables, but I feel creating that loop in pure CSS might be a bit difficult right?

Comment: @boxdox, agreed CSS alone can't do it sensibly. Need JS when historyLength changes during running (assuming that's what's happening, I'm not totally clear).

Comment: @AHaworth It's a svg that has 60(4*`history-length`) g tag childrens and I want to change the color of each `history-length` number of g tag. I thought I was able to do this by extracting tags in js code by using `document.getElementsByTagName('g') but somehow nothing returned, but then when I do this in onClick evenhandler it did return the tags.. so maybe I should figure out why I can't extract tags when it's mounted better than trying creating loop in css.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, but could you clarify when history-length is changed, is it during run time or is the SVG set and not changed at run time?

Comment: @AHaworth it changes on runtime.

Comment: Perhaps you might as well abandon CSS and in the JS when historyLength changes go through each g element and change its fill and stroke attributes. What triggers the change to historyLength?

Comment: @AHaworth Thanks. I thought the same way. I'm making a graph that displays patient vital sign historically and history length is a length of data array of measured data point which includes body temperature, pressure, respiration rate, and so on. So it depends on patients.

Comment: What triggers the change in historyLength - it sounds as though it might be something from e.g. a database on the backend, i.e. not actually 'live' within a JS context?

Comment: @AHaworth Ah, yes you are right. I get the variable from the backend. Sorry for making you confused.

Comment: As it's not changing at runtime (frontend/user action e.g.) then get the backend code to do the calculations and send the right SVG all set up with colors.